# get state of system (ro or rw)

Tags: android

I want to get the state of the system and then show a dialog (toasts at the moment so the code is short) and allow the user to either mount it rw or ro based on the current state.

I used the following code but it didn't work and I'm confused as to why it's not working.

```
File system = new File("/system");
if(system.canWrite()){
    Toast.makeText(Utilities.this, "System is RW", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
    Toast.makeText(Utilities.this, "System is RO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

How can this be done?

**===============================EDIT===============================**

Here is the final code after parsing /proc/mounts for future searchers

```
private boolean readReadWriteFile() {
        File mountFile = new File("/proc/mounts");
        StringBuilder procData = new StringBuilder();
        if(mountFile.exists()) {
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mountFile.toString());
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));
                String data;
                while((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    procData.append(data + "\n");               
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
            if(procData.toString() != null) {
                String[] tmp = procData.toString().split("\n");
                for(int x = 0; x < tmp.length; x++) {
                   //Kept simple here on purpose different devices have different blocks
                    if(tmp[x].contains("/dev/block") && tmp[x].contains("/system")) {
                        if(tmp[x].contains("rw")) {
                            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "System is rw", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return true;
                        } else if(tmp[x].contains("ro")) {
                            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "System is ro", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you query permissions for user. Even if `/system` is remounted as `rw` it does not mean your application will get "write" access to it.

As alternative solution, read `/proc/mounts` file and parse `ro`/`rw` status from there.

Comment: good idea didn't think of that, that should work thanks a ton for the suggestion